# My PECL uploadprogress bar appears, but why doesn't it show any progress?

Tags: 7, files

I installed the PECL uploadprogress bar in php and this is working fine but when I start uploading a file it ends up getting stuck and dissapearing when the file is uploaded.

This is what i see when i start the  upload:

[image: Uploadprogressbar Stuck]

The file is big enough so it doesnt open/close really fast.

But it just ends up being stuck at Starting upload... and not moving the blue bar to the right when its uploading. After a while it just dissapears and says done and i can submit the form fine.

This is how i want it to look like while uploading:

[image]

Comment: 1. How did you install it 2. How do you know it's working? 3. If you go to the site status report, does it confirm it's working there?

Comment: Yes it does its working fine. the file uploads but it just doesnt fill the bar while uploading thats the only problem at the moment.

Comment: Stefan, what about other questions? What is in status report? And when we talk about reports, what's in watchdog? And in your browser JS console?

Comment: @Molot no errors in my console I installed PECL uploadprogress with a .dll file into my ext folder in php so its a php extension. I selected "show upload progress bar" in my webform settings and it shows but it just doesnt fill up and gets stuck. What do you exactly mean with Watchdog?

Comment: Phpinfo shows it as enabled? Watchdog is "recent log messages" in GUI. Also see status report, is upload progress line green, red or blue?

Comment: @Molot Uploadprogress is enabled in phpinfo() In the drupal 7 statusreport its enabled and green: Enabled (PECL uploadprogress) So that looks fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. Debian 8.1, PHP 5.6, Drupal 7.41. Installed it [as per instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2549141) and Drupal status page and phpinfo show as installed.

Comment: Just a wild guess: could it be because of insufficient memory? Can you try to (temporary) increase the available memory with like 25% or so? That's what I typically do when things start to hang/get stuck after "adding" some new module or feature (which might just be too much to still fit in the currently available module). If it does help, I'll transform my "wild guess" in a real answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the (very old) [issue # 633862](https://www.drupal.org/node/633862). Even though it's an old issue, it includes quite a few comments that may help you to find "the clue". E.g. that it it doesn't seem to work for the more "exotic" server configurations.

Comment # 41 states this:

> Apparently secure servers also have an issue with it `https://` won't work with this.

Comment # 43 in that issue also suggest the (sandbox for now)  [upload_progress](https://www.drupal.org/node/2402147) module, here is what that comment includes:

> I have created a little module that uses client-side JavaScript instead of server-side code to display the progress. This will finally bring upload progress to more "exotic" server configurations.

Comment: Thanks. upload_progress with [my patch suggestion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2637750) brings back the broken functionality.

Comment: Great to hear! And "merci" for the bounty! Fingers crossed your patch will help the maintainer of this module (https://www.drupal.org/u/wmnnd) to finally get this sandbox project approved in the "famous" PAR-process ... looks ,like we should think of a way to help achieve that user's outstanding request (for sooooooooo long). PS: anything else I can do to have my answer marked as accepted?

Comment: Hi Pierre, it's not my question so I can't "accept" it. That's why I did the bounty thing. I was considering an edit adding details about the install as it's still quirky (Drupal won't recognise it on status page, so you can't chose progress bar without pecl also installed...).

Comment: Oeps, sorry, of course (I forgot you were not the OPer ...). Maybe some day the OPer may come back to my PS-part of it ... About that "edit adding details ...": how about posting an extra answer, in which you refer to my answer (if that would be needed)? I'd love to "learn" about that part to (probably others also?).

Comment: I disabled https on server, tried with pecl install and tried to compile it myself and in both cases it doesn't work properly. It shows like in first post and it doesn't fill it as upload goes.

Comment: @milovan : thanks for the extra comment. To be honest, I have no other inspiration for other attempts, or further debugging (sorry). Do you have any other thoughts, comments, whatever (which might help to get more inspiration ...)?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens ok I did a further testing. Unfortunately, it appears that indeed in default Drupal everything works just with pecl install uploadprogress, and some module seems to be messing up with my Drupal insance I initially tested on (with a lot of contributed and custom modules and theme as well). I will do further investigation which module is causing me problem and update here. After that, I will test on SSL to make sure what's the status with ssl sites and update as well. Let me just gather more test results, and we can discuss what can we do next.

Answer (score 1):

Hi all :) About this challenge with PECL uploadprogress bar showing, but not showing any progress, here are two additional options to choose from

**First Option**

Have you tried to first **upgrade your server-side versions, packages, and libraries** to meet PECL upload progress's minimum requirements?

We struggled for months trying to display the progress status using PECL uploadprogress. In our case it turns out the source of the challenge was that the server-side versions, packages, and libraries were too old. As a result they do not support PECL upload progress minimum requirements.

**Second Option**

Until that server is upgraded, to resolve this challenge we found a fantastic alternative. PECL uploadprogress is great. But in some cases and for newcomers it might be challenging to install and configure. Mostly because it depends on server-side libraries and configuration. If you prefer a client-side upload progress, you might be interested in this **File Resumable Upload ([file_resup](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup))** module. The benefits are:

- Easy installation. Because no dependencies, except Drupal core File itself, and no libraries.
- Bypass PHP's upload limits
- Works with both 32bit and 64 bit servers
- Allows to upload large files (over 2 GB)

Thanks to Brad for his discovery. Source, documentation, and details at https://www.drupal.org/node/793264#gen-faq---alternatives